# How to access views for a given video on YouTube throughout time?

Tags: youtube

When you watch a YouTube video, many of the videos have a "statistics" option below, where you can see the views of the video throughout time, since the video has been posted.
[image]

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to access the raw data behind the graph, and I was wondering if there is any way to do this? I've looked in the YouTube API, but can't find anything there. If any of you are familiar with any way to do this, inside or outside YouTube itself (an external source would also be just fine), I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You can get number of views via Youtube Analytics & Reporting APIs. from [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/v1/reports/metrics#views).

> **View metrics**
>
> **views (core metric):**
>   The number of times that a video was viewed. In a playlist report, the metric indicates the number of times that a video was viewed in the context of a playlist. The YouTube Help Center provides additional information about how views are reported. This is a core metric and is subject to the Deprecation Policy.
>
> **red_views**
>   The number of times that a video was viewed by YouTube Red members.
>
> **views_percentage (core metric)**
>   The percentage of viewers who were logged in when watching the video or playlist. This is a core metric and is subject to the Deprecation Policy.